# How to configure OraOLEDB connection string

Tags: vba, oracle, oraoledb

I need some help to set up a connection to Oracle DB.

I have an Excel VBA application using following working connection string setting up proper connection to existing Oracle database:

```
Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle; 
Data Source = XXXXSSA5; 
User Id = [USERNAME]; Password = [PASSWORD];
```

Recently the database was moved to the new localisation, the following connection string is working fine with sqlplus, however I have no idea how to properly represent it as OraOLEDB connection string:

```sql
[USERNAME]/[PASSWORD]@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=symbol.server.company.net)(Port=1731))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DDDB1044_APP)))
```

I tried with filling in recent template with a new data:

```
Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle; 
Data Source = DDDB1044_APP; 
User Id = [USERNAME]; Password = [PASSWORD];
```

However I suppose that I'll need to somehow pass Host name to the connection string and probably the Port too, as I am receiving the message: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you define an alias in your `tnsnames.ora` file like this:

```
DDDB1044_APP = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=symbol.server.company.net)(Port=1731))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DDDB1044_APP)))
```

Then use this alias `Data Source = DDDB1044_APP;`

If you don't like to work with alias then just put the entire connection to it:

```
Data Source = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=symbol.server.company.net)(Port=1731))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DDDB1044_APP)))"
```